# Adding Spring Security as a dependency causes the app behave differently

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

Briefly: weird thing happens when I add `spring-boot-starter-security` to my `build.gradle`. Here's my distilled code (there's no other code at all):

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(AppConfiguration.class, args);
        } catch(BeanCreationException e) {
            System.out.printf("HURRAY: %s\n", e.getBeanName());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan          // !!! NOTE: extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter !!!
    public static class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private MyService myService;
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyService {
        public MyService() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: "junit", name: "junit", version: "4.11"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: "1.0.0.RC5"
    // compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-security", version: "1.0.0.RC5" // HERE
}
```

The behavior I expect is that `BeanCreationException` will be thrown and `catch` will print `HURRAY`. And it works this way. The weird thing happens when I try to add a `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency in `build.gradle`. Once I uncomment that line, the exception thrown is `ApplicationContextException`. If I recursively call `getCause()`, the result is like this:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException
```

You can see, there's no `BeanCreationException` at all.

When I run the app, [the logs clearly say](https://gist.github.com/loki2302/9842044) that there WAS a `BeanCreationException` somewhere.

Is there a reliable approach to catch that `BeanCreationException`?

Comment: I guess there is no `BeanCreationException` because something else went wrong. Not sure what. Can you show the stack trace? (Ignore that. Just saw the logs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeanCreationException` is being thrown in another thread (Spring Security is a filter and filters get initialized in a special way in an embedded container). I'm not sure we can force Tomcat to use the main thread (I tried once and gave up, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's impossible). If you can improve it please make a suggestion in github.

Comment: Thank you Dave. One interesting thing I just discovered is that this "issue" (issue?) only appears when I use Tomcat. It properly throws `BeanCreationException` when I switch to Jetty.